# Как правильно написать запрос к БД?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть PHP обработчик для редактирования данных пользователя.

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT email,phone FROM `bd_users` WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `bd_users` WHERE `id` = '".$id."')" );
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
if($row['email'] == $email){
    $_SESSION["error_messages"] = "<p class='mesage_error'>Пользователь с таким e-mail уже зарегистрирован</p>";   
        header("Location: ***");
        exit();
} 
if($row['phone'] == $phone){
    $_SESSION["error_messages"] = "<p class='mesage_error'>Пользователь с таким номером телефона уже зарегистрирован</p>";  
        header("Location: ***");
        exit();
}
$result_query_insert = $mysqli->query("UPDATE `bd_users` SET email='".$email."', pass='".$pass."', phone='".$phone."', name='".$name."', fname='".$fname."', otname='".$otname."' WHERE `id` = '".$id."'");
if(!$result_query_insert){    
$_SESSION["error_messages"] = "<p class='mesage_error' >Ошибка запроса на добавления пользователя в БД</p>";
header("Location: ***");
exit();
}else{
$_SESSION["success_messages"] = "<p class='success_message'>Редактирование прошло успешно!!!</p>";
header("Location: ***");
}
```

Так вот, по идее он должен перезаписывать данные пользователя(что он в принципе и делает, т.е. сам обработчик свое дело делает)

Загвоздка вот в чем - если поменять емайл(телефон) пользователя на тот, что уже есть в БД, то он пишет: "Ошибка запроса на добавление пользователя в БД", а должен писать ту ошибку, где пользователь ввел совпадающие с другими пользователя данные(емайл или телефон).

Поля мыла и телефона уникальны(т.е я понимаю почему мне пишет, что не может быть добавлено это значение в поле таблицы). Но как сделать чтобы мне вывело Erorr именно про то поле, которое пользователь ввел совпадающим не знаю.

Comment: Делайте селект и если нет ошибок при которых не должен выполняться запрос на вставку тогда выполняйте запрос на изменение, если хоть одна ошибка есть запрос на обновление данных не делайте. Сейчас у Вас запрос на изменение отработает потому что ошибки совпадения вы никак не обрабатываете кроме вывода информации.

Comment: Вы первый запрос в MySQL выполнять пробовали ? Любой запрос перебирает записи и для каждой из записей проверяет условие (грубо говоря) и если условие дало истину - то запись появляется на выходе. теперь посмотрим на ваш запрос: скажем $id=5 и такой записи в БД нет. проверка начинается с записи с id=1. проверяем not exists(select ... id=5) , да, действительно не существует, значит истина, значит запись с id=1 надо вернуть, переходим к записи id=2, опять проверяем то же условие, оно разумеется опять верно и мы возвращаем и ее. Короче, ваш запрос возвращает _все строки_ таблицы, если искомой нет

Comment: И вообще я не пойму логики, которая должна была бы быть, если бы запрос был верный. вы ищите некую запись по id и при этом пытаетесь сообщить, что запись с таким email уже есть. но как так получается, что по id вы пытаетесь искать именно ту запись, в которой такой же email ?

Comment: P.S. никогда не подставляйте переменные непосредственно в текст запроса, вас взломают через день после того как поместите это в интернет. _Всегда_ используйте подготовленные выражения и привязку значений http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: Логика такая - есть БД, в которой находится email пользователя (под которым он например зашел вместо логина). ОН заходит на страницу редактирования(хочет например поменять email). Меняет его. Нажимает сохранить. Данные уходят в обработчик, где где я хочу сравнить значение этого email со значениями email других пользователей ИСКЛЮЧАЯ текущую запись (для того чтобы если пользователь не менял email, а менял другое поле, мне не выдало ошибку)

Comment: Например такая запись: SELECT `email` FROM `bd_users` WHERE `email` IN ('".$email."') даст мне то, что если пользователь не менял свой email, а менял другое поле, мне выдаст ошибку, т.к. это значение тоже проверяется. Вопрос как раз в том как исключить эту проверку(если пользователь не менял свой email, а менял другое поле, но в то же время проверить есть ли этот email в других столбцах таблицы БД)

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте сделать так

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT email,phone FROM `bd_users` WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `bd_users` WHERE `id` = '".$id."')" );
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
if ($row['email'] == $email) {
    $_SESSION["error_messages"] = "<p class='mesage_error'>Пользователь с таким e-mail уже зарегистрирован</p>";   
    header("Location: ***");
    exit();
} 
if ($row['phone'] == $phone) {
    $_SESSION["error_messages"] = "<p class='mesage_error'>Пользователь с таким номером телефона уже зарегистрирован</p>";  
        header("Location: ***");
        exit();
} else {
    $result_query_insert = $mysqli->query("UPDATE `bd_users` SET 
                                    email='".$email."', pass='".$pass."', phone='".$phone."', name='".$name."', fname='".$fname."', otname='".$otname."' WHERE `id` = '".$id."'");
    if (!$result_query_insert) {    
        $_SESSION["error_messages"] = "<p class='mesage_error' >Ошибка 
            запроса на добавления пользователя в БД</p>";
        header("Location: ***");
        exit();
    } else {
        $_SESSION["success_messages"] = "<p 
            class='success_message'>Редактирование прошло успешно!!!</p>";
        header("Location: ***");
   }
}
```

Comment: Все равно выводит, что "ошибка запроса на добавление....", а не нужную ошибку. И разве не должен срабатывать exit(); после того как идет сравнение $row['email']==$email. По идее же если там равно, то переход по хедеру и $_SESSION["error_messages"] принимает значение той ошибки, где была остановка скрипта. Не должно же идти дальнейшее выполнение этого обработчика.

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо нашел решение.

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT `email` FROM `bd_users`
WHERE `email` IN ('".$email."') AND `email` NOT IN ('".$s_email."')");
```

Перед этим, на странице аутентификации засунул в сессию значение email. После апдейта БД так же засунул значение email в сессию(чтобы сравнивалось с обновленным значением email). Скорее всего, я как начинающий нубешник принялся изобретать свой велосипед и наверняка есть более лаконичное или правильное решение, но раз и это работает...